# How to exclude child node in the output using xslt 1.0?

Tags: templates, xslt

See my xsltfiddle:

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKr/3

In the output on row one there is a date stamp that I don't want in it. It is in the source xml under

```
<analystePurchaseInvoices>
    <currentDate>2018-12-03T14:50:08</currentDate>
</analystePurchaseInvoices>
```

I want that date out. But I don't know how.

Comment: Please post your code here, not in links. And try to minimize it to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet has only one template, and that template matches the `purchaseInvoice` element. You have no template matching the root `analystePurchaseInvoices` element or its other child `currentDate`. Therefore these elements are processed by the [built-in templates rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule). This results in the text contained in `currentDate` being copied to the output.

You can avoid this in a number of ways. For example, you could add an empty template to handle `currentDate`:

```
<xsl:template match="currentDate"/>
```

Or you could exclude `currentDate` from being processed at all by:

```
<xsl:template match="/analystePurchaseInvoices">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="purchaseInvoice"/> 
</xsl:template>
```